# leetcode No 228, runtime error

Tags: python

I have written a solution for leetcode No. 228. It works on Eclipse but when I run it in leetcode oj, it keeps saying:

```
Runtime Error Message:
Line 31: NameError: global name 'Solution' is not defined"
```

I attached the code:

```
def solution(l):
        s = []
        left = 0
        right = 0
        while left < len(l):
            if left == len(l) - 1:
                s += [str(l[left])]
                return s    
            elif l[right + 1] == l[right] + 1:
                right += 1
            else:
                s += [str(l[left]) + "->" + str(l[right])]
                left = right + 1
                right = left

print(solution([0,1,2,4,5,7]))
```

Can someone help me with it? I don't think it's the problem with the code, as it works in Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: There's no name `Solution` in the code you are showing.

Comment: The function is named solution, I don't understand

Comment: at a guess leetcode expects a method named `Solution` not `solution`

Comment: @JoranBeasley That seems reasonable. I remember something similar happening on CodeEval

Comment: @Joran Beasley, I changed the function to be Solution, and now it gives me, "Line 32: TypeError: Solution() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)", I am so confused, it is not Line 32, and I did give an input. Still everything works in eclipse.  Can you give me some suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: @Alice Are you sure you should call the function yourself and not simply write it? I don't know leetcode that well

Comment: @Joran, yes, I used the name: Solution, leetcode provided, it doesn't complain about the name anymore, the only problem is it keeps saying "takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)""

Comment: @Alice I checked the leetcode question. There's a hardcoded snippet to start you off on the site. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from [228. Summary Ranges](https://leetcode.com/problems/summary-ranges/) on leetcode.com:

```
class Solution(object):
    def summaryRanges(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
```

I think you're meant to add your code to a function named `summaryRanges` inside a *class* named `Solution`. Adding your code (which I haven't tested btw.) would give this:

```
class Solution(object):
    def summaryRanges(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        s = []
        left = 0
        right = 0
        while left < len(nums):
            if left == len(nums) - 1:
                s += [str(nums[left])]
                return s    
            elif nums[right + 1] == nums[right] + 1:
                right += 1
            else:
                s += [str(nums[left]) + "->" + str(nums[right])]
                left = right + 1
                right = left
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works this time. Thanks. I don't  have points, sorry can't vote for your answer.

Comment: @Alice Cool. Glad it worked! I'm not an expert on the point system but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) says *"answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)"*. Maybe we'd both get some silly interwebz points if you accepted the answer :)

Comment: @ jDo, I didn't know how to accept an answer before. I did it.

Comment: @Alice I see. Thanks :)